# Converting yearmon to numeric format but how to keep the class 'yearmon' rather than 'character'?

Tags: r, class, date, character, xts

I have an xts object so when using index() function it is "2002-01-01"

```
x <- "2002-01-01"
x <- as.yearmon(x)
```

This makes x look like

```
"Jan 2002"
```

Then I convert it to a numeric format by doing:

```
x <- format(x, "%Y-%m")
```

Resulting in x looking like:

```
"2002-01"
```

However this changes the class of the value to be 'character' and I need it to be in a yearmon or some other date class that looks like '2002-01' so it can go back into the index() of the xts object.

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `format` formats the data -- it does not convert it to numeric.  Internally yearmon class objects are stored as numeric.  It is only when you display them that they show as "Jan 2002", say.   Please explain further what your objective is.  `"yearmon"` is already a date class. You don't need to convert it at all to use it in xts, to sort it to plot it, to compare it, etc.

Comment: when using it as yearmon and running a trading strategy through blotter, the function updatePortf() does not like it in that format and I was assuming that is because it has the word "Jan" in it. Maybe my assumption is wrong but the strategy works when it is in a %Y-%m-%d format but it is taking days to run the code so I have been told if the date is in a yearmon format it will run quicker.

Comment: There is no word "Jan" in a `"yearmon"` object. That can only appear if you or your function tries to create a character string object out of it using `format`.(or `as.character`).but at that point it is a character string, not `"yearmon"`.